# Странное исключение в модульных тестах Convert.ToBolean

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, .net-core

Использую фреймворк [msunit](/questions/tagged/msunit). При обычном запуске программы `Convert.ToBoolean("Tr1ue");` или `Convert.ToBoolean("1");` выдает стандартное исключение, указанное в официальной документации:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   Boolean.'

---

Есть такой тестовый метод:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("Tr1ue")]
[DataRow("F4alse")]
[DataRow("1")]
[DataRow("0")]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FormatException))]
public void ConvertToBoleanException(string a, bool expexted)
{
    Convert.ToBoolean(a);
}
```

Данный тест почему-то не проходит, и выдает следующее сообщение:

> Message: Test method threw exception
>   System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException, but exception
>   System.FormatException was expected. Exception message:
>   System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count
>   mismatch.

**Вопрос:** Почему метод `Convert.ToBolean()` выдает исключение `TargetParameterCountException` в модульных тестах?

P.S.: это исключение не указано как возвращаемое в документации.

Comment: Это не «странное» исключение. Вы тесты проводите неправильно. У Вас в функции 2 параметра, а во всех `DataRowAttribute` - 1. Поэтому рефлексия, используемая тестами, и выдаёт ошибку, что число параметров не соответствует требуемому

Comment: @Kir_Antipov действительно, опечатался. Спасибо! Вопрос вызван опечаткой, следовательно подлежит закрытию.

Comment: не закрывайте) Будет повод написать ответ (чуть подправив вопрос). Думаю, будет полезно кому-нибудь

Comment: @Kir_Antipov так мож вы его и напишете?

Comment: Вопрос не вызван опечаткой, ответ писать можно и нужно.

Comment: @AK Вообще да, странно что он ожидал "System.FormatException was expected". Это первоначально и смутило меня.

Comment: @tym32167 таки напишу)